# Is there a mouseOver workaround for IE8 and Firefox in WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

The `moveToElement` of WebDriver does not work in Firefox and IE. It works just fine in Chrome browser.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);       
builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(Loader.OR.getProperty(object))))
                            .moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(data)))
                            .click();
Action selectMultiple = builder.build();
selectMultiple.perform();
```

Again, works with Chrome but not with IE or Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javacript for it, but, unfortunately, script is different for IE and Firefox/Chrome:

```
if (_browserName == BrowserName.InternetExplorer)
   {
        script = "var evt = document.createEventObject();" +
                 "arguments[0].fireEvent('onmouseover', evt);";
   }
else
  {
      script = "var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');" +
               "evt.initMouseEvent('mouseover',true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);" +
               "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evt);";
 }
((IJavaScriptExecutor)QuestWebDriver.CurrentDriver).ExecuteScript(script, element);
```

For IE these selenium native method works fine for me:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(element).Perform();
```